# sep=' ' is not working. what is the reason?

Tags: python-3.x

In the `print` function, `sep` is not working as my output shows all the sequential numbers all together. But the desired output will be organized with a space among every number.

```
num=0
for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10):
        print (num,sep=' ', end="")
        num+=1
    print("\r")
```

my desired output should be:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
.....................
```

every two numbers should have a space between them. But instead I am getting this:

```
0123456789
10111213141516171819
20212223242526272829
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `sep` (which already has a default value of `' '` anyway) when you're printing all the numbers in a single `print` statement (`print(1, 2, 3, ..., sep = '-')  =>  '1-2-3-...'`), but since you're printing each on its own, you should utilize the `end` parameter instead (whose value is printed after all the arguments of the `print` function are printed):

```
num = 0
for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10):
        print(num, end = ' ')
        num += 1
    print('\r')
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```